# how to creat a operator[][] to a two dimensional array(matrix)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

as an exercise i got to implamant a operator[][] to a matrix class. The compiler makes problems and does not let me even start. does anyone have any iddea why?

```
template <class Type>
Type Matrix<Type>::operator[][](int i, int j)
{
    return getElement(i, j);
}
```

the method need to return the place [row][col] in the matrix.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no `operator[][]` in C++. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to resort to `operator()`:

```
template <class Type>
Type Matrix<Type>::operator()(int i, int j)
{
    return getElement(i, j);
}
```

If you want to make your life harder, you can use a workaround by overloading `operator[]` such that it returns a proxy object which *also* overloads `operator[]`. For the caller, the chained `operator[]` calls will work as if there was an `operator[][]`.

Comment: thanks but my teacher ask to use this signature.. can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggested you can do it with a function but if you really want to do this you will need to return an object from the operator[] of the matrix and then this object will need an operator[] which will return the type. Example:

```
template <class Type>
class Matrix {
public:
    class Row{
    public:
        Type operator[](int col) {

        }
    };
    Row operator[](int row) {

    }
};
```

...

```
Matrix<int> m;
m[1][2];
```